# Linux Screen; How do I make screen persistent with the -X command?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm running screen with the following command:

```
screen -dms -X buildscript.py
```

This executes the buildscript.py file and runs it as a daemon.  Now, when the build script fails, screen automatically terminates (and I don't get to see the error messages)!

How can I make it so an -X to a script will NOT be terminated if that script fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wrapper /path/buildscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildscript.py
bash
```

And command

```
screen -dms -X buildscript.sh
```